# Is Weka's JRIP updateable?

Tags: weka

I have a large dataset and I am using Weka with the Python wrapper to train the RIPPER algorithm. Can I use Weka's updateable interface for incrementally training the JRIP algorithm (RIPPER)?

How can I train the large dataset with WEKA's python wrapper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for a Weka classifier to support incremental training, in needs to implement the [weka.classifiers.Updateable](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/UpdateableClassifier.html) interface.

However, [JRip](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/rules/JRip.html) does not implement that, as you can see from the *All Implemented Interfaces:* section of its Javadoc.